Install files only for 32/64 bit with Inno Setup
My application can run in 32 and 64 bit (.NET Any CPU) and uses a native SQLite DLL that lies in the x86 and x64 subdirectory. Now when installing the app, it is known whether the system is 32 or 64 bit and it cannot change later. So I'd like to only copy the relevant file for this system and nothing unused.
I tried it like this:
Source: "..\bin\{#BuildConfig}\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion 64bit
Source: "..\bin\{#BuildConfig}\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion 32bit

But none of the files was actually installed. After reading the documentation it seems that these flags are doing something unexpected. I don't know what they do, the description doesn't make sense to me. And the web couldn't find any way to conditionally install either of the files. I can just leave out the flags and always install both files which I wanted to avoid.
Can InnoSetup do this? Without extensive scripting only for these simple file entries?
